# How to disable vim's indentation of switch case php?

Tags: php, vim

Hello can someone please help me, with switch cases incorrectly indenting in php.

My current code is:

```
public function getSeverity($sanitizedResult, array $statuses, $format)
    {             
        switch ($format) {
            case 'namedInteger':
                return $statuses[$sanitizedResult]['result'];
            case 'namedString':
                return $statuses['currentVersion'] == $sanitizedResult ? 0 : 1;
            default:
                throw new \Exception("Unknown result format given " . $format);
        }
    }
```

The above code is correctly formatted however when i use visual line to format all my code it turns into the code below which is wrong and code_sniffer will shout at me.

```
    public function getSeverity($sanitizedResult, array $statuses, $format)
    {             
        switch ($format) {
        case 'namedInteger':
            return $statuses[$sanitizedResult]['result'];
        case 'namedString':
            return $statuses['currentVersion'] == $sanitizedResult ? 0 : 1;
        default:
            throw new \Exception("Unknown result format given " . $format);
        }
    }
```

Is there a magic command that i can put into my vim file that would stop this even if i format with visual line??

I have already tried `:set cinoptions=l1`

Thank you

Comment: [vi.se] may be a better place to ask this.

Comment: We don't even know what method you currently use to format your code.